# Corrupt web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, web, web-config

Today I encountered an error that I haven't seen before and hoping one of you can help to clarify.

I have a web server that hosts multiple sites and web services. This server does not have any auto updating turned on or received any updates recently, but yet one of my web services was suddenly returning 404's and 500's this morning (the service is called every 15 minutes). As I began digging the error messages were very generic and frankly not making any sense. After browsing the web without any success, I decided to replace the web.config, only because one of the error messages suggested something had recently changed in the web.config(nothing changed to my knowledge). I quickly grabbed a config file from a staging environment, put it in place of the old config and the services were back up and running. Can anyone explain how or what could have caused this? This service has been running for months without any changes. A visual diff of the old config and the new config file revealed only white space changes.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since there are only white space changes, I'd assume that web.config text encoding has been changed and IIS cannot read it.

Try to open the original web.config in Notepad++ and make sure the encoding is UTF. If it's not, try to change it back.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what do you mean by that? the text encoding?

Comment: Yes, I mean text/file encoding

Comment: how would that have randomly changed?

Comment: @DmitryProkorym Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should edit this answer to clarify what you mean a bit, and propose a possible cause and solution. :)